# How to save order in database table?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

Maybe strang, but I can't find a (good) post in SO about my question..

I have some menuitems, and I want to let the user save them in a custom order in a DB-table. I'm using the jquery UI to let them place the items in the good order (with sortable on the tbody-element). My situation now is really simple, but It will be more complex in the future (submenu, special pages, ...)..

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

*My question:* **What are my possibilities to save the order of the items in a databasetable. What are the disadvantages of that possibilities?**

I was thinking to save it in a database table withe the page (id) and a weight.
How higher, the less important it will be (database table has to be finetuned)..

```
CREATE TABLE `pageweight` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The possibilities I see:

I can save it in jQuery, by selecting the tablerows in my tablebody. And for each table row I have an Ajaxrequest.. that updates / creates a row in the database..

I can work with hidden fields in my form. The id/name-attribute can contain the menuitemid and the value is the weight. jQuery can update it every time there is a change? Then in PHP I handle every field and let it save..

Or are there other ways? Especially when it becomes bigger..

Comment: Fastest way: single *save* request to server, single insert query to database.

Comment: Use charset `utf8mb4`. Don't bother with latin1 or anything else, they will cause you headaches.

Comment: Asking **opinion based** questions will most likely result in your question being closed. You may want to consider rewriting your question to be more psecific and less opinion based. Please read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help section.

Comment: Changed some words.. I use UTF 8 ;-). Was default of my database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most basic method would be to iterate each row and combine each cell into an object, saved to an array.

```
function getTableData(tObj){
  var keys = [];
  $("thead tr th").each(function(i, el){
    keys.push($(el).text().trim());
  });
  var rows = [];
  $("tbody tr", tObj).each(function(i, el){
    var r = {};
    $.each(keys, function(k, v){
      if(v == "#"){
        r["id"] = parseInt($("td", el).eq(k).text().trim());
      } else {
        r[v] = $("td", el).eq(k).text().trim();
      }
    });
    rows.push(r);
  });
}

var pageWeights = getTableData($("table"));
```

This function will read the header row and created keys. Assuming they are `id`, `page`, and `weight` or any other values, it will collect them. It will then capture the associated data for each body row. If you perform `console.log(pageWeights)`, you see something like:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  page: "Title",
  weight: "2"
},{
  id: 2,
  page: "Title",
  weight: "4"
},{
  id: 3,
  page: "Title",
  weight: "6"
}];
```

You can then post this to a Server-Side script:

```
$.post("savetable.php", {
  data: JSON.stringify(pageWeights)
}, function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

If your table is more complex, this may not be the best solution. For example, if the table contains 100 or 1000 rows, this might create a very large amount of data that cannot be passed via POST or may cause the browser to perform poorly. Consider changing the function:

- Gather a specific number of rows
- Look for only changed data and send only those updates
- Reduce the amount of data presented in the table

You may also want to look at using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) library. This helps with a lot of the things you might want to do.

Answer (score -2):

I dont' think it's ideal to save each setting to each record in the table. Your table will be bulky than your real content.  Therefore you are wasting space and query time on your table design.
I would recommend to save your "user settings" in one single record, like JSON or TEXT formatted record inside a table.  Loading time is lesser.